# Grep's word boundaries include spaces?

Tags: grep, words

I tried to use grep to search for lines containing the word "bead" using "\b" but it doesn't find the lines containing the word "bead" separated by space. I tried this script:

```
cat in.txt | grep -i "\bbead\b" > out.txt
```

I get results like

- BEAD-air.JPG
- Bead, 3 sided MET DP110317.jpg
- Bead. -2819 (FindID 10143).jpg
- Bead(Gem), Artefacts of Phu Hoa site(Dong Nai province).jpg
- Romano-British pendant amulet (bead) (FindID 241983).jpg

But I don't get the results like

- Bead fun.jpg

Instead of getting some 2,000 lines, I'm only getting 92 lines

My OS is Windows 10 - 64 bit but I'm using grep 2.5.4 from the GnuWin32 package.

I've also tried the MSYS2, which includes grep 3.0 but it does the same thing.

And then, how can I search for words separated by space?

**LATER EDIT:**
It looks like grep has problems with big files. My input file is 2.4 GB in size. With smaller files, it works - I reported the bug here: https://sourceforge.net/p/getgnuwin32/discussion/554300/thread/03a84e6b/

Comment: Maybe that's possible: `grep -i '\bbead\b'`

Comment: Works for me. How could you use `cat` on windows?

Comment: @Toto - I'm using the GnuWin32 package. It contains all the Linux tools.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing normally should work but there are ways of setting what is and is not considered a word boundary. Rather than worry about it please try this instead:

```
cat in.txt | grep -iP "\bbead(\b|\s)" > out.txt
```

The P option adds in Perl regular expression power and the \s matches any sort of space character. The Or Bar `|` separates options within the parens `( )`

While you are waiting for grep to be fixed you could use another tool if it is available to you. E.g.

```
perl -lane 'print if (m/\bbead\b/i);' in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: That's good to know, thank you. It looks like there is a bug in grep when processing large files though - I updated my question and I included the bug report link

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
cat in.txt | grep -wi "bead"
```

`-w` provides you a whole word search